# Difficulty in finding the Range of x

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

$x^2 - | x-2 | + 6 > 0 $ , where x belongs to $R$

I am not sure about my own approach to this ques.
I solved it as:

$x^2 + 6 > | x-2 |$  , thereafter i got 2 cases

Case 1: $-(x^2 + 6) < (x - 2)$ , which finally gave, $x^2 + x + 4 > 0 $
Case 2: $ (x^2 + 6) > (x - 2)$ , which finally gave, $x^2 - x + 8 > 0 $

Both the above equations have no Real solutions, and since they have asked the Range of x and not $F(x)$, is it correct to say : Range of x is a particular set of Complex Nos. with an empty set of Real Nos.

All suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: If the $2$  inequalities have no real roots, that means that that the initial inequality is satisfied by every real number.

Comment: Find the minimum value of both the quadratic functions, which is $f(-b/2a)$, where $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. I the output is greater than zero, then the functions are greater than zero for all $x$.

Comment: Maybe they meant to ask: find the subset of elements $x$ for wich this inequality holds (and called that set "the range of $x$"). Then the answer is $\mathbb R$. It holds for any $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ drhab: Asking humbly, is your comment based on the fact that $x^2$ with a +ve coefficient is driving this particular equation, and no matter what Real value of x is fed, the output would always give a +ve value, thereby satisfying the inequality.

Comment: Yes, the inequality is true for $x$ "ranging" over $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your inequalities are satisfied by any real number, since they are quadratic graphs that lie over the $x$-axis.

All in all, your inequality is satisfied over the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, a sketch should be enough to convince you. (blue is $x^2 +6$ and $|x-2|$ is in red)

[image]